# HBase throws TableNotFoundException when the table exists

Tags: hbase

The following code

```
private def deleteTable(tableName: String): Unit = {
 val tableNames = admin.listTableNames()
    println(s"HBase has the following tables: ${tableNames.map(_.toString).toList}")
    tableNames.find(_.getNameAsString == tableName) match {
      case Some(matchedTableName) =>
        admin.disableTable(matchedTableName)
        admin.deleteTable(matchedTableName)
        println(s"Table $tableName was found in HBase and deleted.")
      case None => println(s"Table $tableName was not in HBase.")
    }
}
```

Would throw

```
17/10/02 20:45:22 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException): XXXX
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException): XXXX
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.DisableTableProcedure.prepareDisable(DisableTableProcedure.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.DisableTableProcedure.executeFromState(DisableTableProcedure.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.DisableTableProcedure.executeFromState(DisableTableProcedure.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.StateMachineProcedure.execute(StateMachineProcedure.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.Procedure.doExecute(Procedure.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.execProcedure(ProcedureExecutor.java:1148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.execLoop(ProcedureExecutor.java:943)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.execLoop(ProcedureExecutor.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.access$400(ProcedureExecutor.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor$2.run(ProcedureExecutor.java:498)
```

This makes no sense to me as the table name can be retrieved from admin but when disabling it, suddenly the table cannot be found.

EDIT:
On an HBase shell, I tried

```
hbase(main):011:0> user_permission 'XXXX'
User                                                         Namespace,Table,Family,Qualifier:Permission                                                                                                                                      

ERROR: DISABLED: Security features are not available
```

Comment: Looks like the user running the script has not enough privileges to access the table. Can you check this?

Comment: @Miguel Does my check result imply there is no permission issue?